# Getting notification from Sql Server

Tags: c#, sql, .net, sql-server, service-broker

I'd like to use `SqlDependency` class in my winforms application :

```
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private int changeCount = 0; 
        private const string statusMessage = "{0} changes have occurred."; 

        private static SqlConnection connection = null;
        private static SqlCommand command = null;
        private static SqlDependency dependency;

        private static SqlCommand command1 = null;
        private static SqlDependency dependency1;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            button1.Enabled = CanRequestNotifications();
            this.FormClosed += Form1_FormClosed;
            if (connection == null)
            {
                connection = new SqlConnection(GetConnectionString());
            }

            if (command == null)
            {
                command = new SqlCommand("procCreationUser", connection);
                command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            }
            dependency = new SqlDependency(command);

            if (connection == null)
            {
                connection = new SqlConnection(GetConnectionString());
            }

            if (command1 == null)
            {
                command1 = new SqlCommand("procSelectionUser", connection);
                command1.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            }
            dependency1 = new SqlDependency(command1);
            GetData();
        }

        private void GetData()
        {

            SqlDependency.Start(GetConnectionString());
            if (connection.State != ConnectionState.Open) connection.Open();
            using (var dr = command.ExecuteReader())
            {
                dependency.OnChange += new OnChangeEventHandler(dependency_OnChange);
            }

            using (var dr = command1.ExecuteReader())
            {
                dependency1.OnChange += new OnChangeEventHandler(dependency_OnChange);
            }

        }
        private string GetConnectionString()
        {
            return @"Data Source=PRT-12\SQLEXPRESS; Initial Catalog=TestNotification;Integrated Security=True";
        }


        private void dependency_OnChange(object sender, SqlNotificationEventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Notification");      
        }

    }
```

I created two stored procedures : `procCreationUser` for creation and `procSelectionUser` to select users.

When I launched the application, and I clicked into the button and insert a new row in the database I haven't no notification !!!!!

1. How can I fix my code?
2. Is it the best way to get notification from Sql Server?

Comment: You need to tidy up your code, it's a bit all over the place.

Comment: Have you enabled Service Broker in your Database.

Comment: @DevD yes it is activated

Comment: You still have some unnecessary code, why do you need a `using reader` around `dependency.onChange()`? Looks like with your edit you also removed the code which updates the data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend you read these:

- [Using SQL Trace to Troubleshoot Query Notifications](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190758(v=sql.105).aspx)
- [Troubleshooting Query Notifications: Checking a Subscription](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177438(v=sql.105).aspx)
- [Troubleshooting Query Notifications: Subscription Registered, Event Message Not Produced, Subscription Removed](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191490(v=sql.105).aspx)
- [Troubleshooting Dialogs](http://rusanu.com/2005/12/20/troubleshooting-dialogs/)
- [The Mysterious Notification](http://rusanu.com/2006/06/17/the-mysterious-notification/)

You need to establish that the following event all occur:

- your query creates a notification subscription. Check the Profiler events mentioned in above articles, check in [`sys.dm_qn_subscriptions`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187793.aspx)
- check that modifying the data invalidates the subscription, use the Profiler  events mentioned in above articles
- check that notification messages get delivered, specially check `transmission_status` in [`sys.transmission_queue`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190336.aspx)
- check that your code has succesfully set up the notification listener. Your app **must** call [`SqlDependency.Start`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldependency.start(v=vs.110).aspx) once per appdomain  and ideally should call [`SqlDependency.Stop`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms224869(v=vs.110).aspx) when the appdomain shuts down.

Once you get the notification flowing make sure you check and honor the `Source`, `Info` and `Type` in your [`SqlNotificationEventArgs`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlnotificationeventargs(v=vs.110).aspx) arg. Not all combinations indicate success, the notification may also fire immediately indicating a problem with your subscription.

Also, a small tidbits with your code:

- you need to hook up the SqlDependency *before* executing the query:

  dependency.OnChange += new OnChangeEventHandler(dependency_OnChange);
    using (var dr = command.ExecuteReader()) {
      while (dr.Read()) {
         ...
      }
    }
- you need to call `SqlDependency.Start` *once per appdomain*. Try calling it in Main, before displaying the Form

Answer (score 0):

Normally you should subscribe to event first `dependency.OnChange += new OnChangeEventHandler(dependency_OnChange);` and only after that you will receive updates from `command.ExecuteReader()`.
For two separate commands it is probably better to have two separate `SqlDependency`.

Comment: please see my edit, even I change my code like that, I get no notification

Comment: You still subscribe too late. `dependency1.OnChange += new OnChangeEventHandler(dependency_OnChange);` should be in `Form1()` method.

Comment: It is executed in the method Getdata called in the constructor!!

Comment: I've edited my comment a bit, it probably makes more sense now.